# Convert Gremlin or SQL to Cypher

Tags: sql, neo4j, cypher, orientdb, gremlin

Is it possible to convert a **SQL** or a **Gremlin** query into **Cypher** for Neo4j?

If it is possible, how can I do it?

Comment: other than that a graph db with an sql to query it seems very difficult to work with. sql quickly gets crowded, yet it is designed for rdbms of past in the past, not designed for graphdbs. A declarative lang does better with graph data model, like Cypher of Neo4j, by the way I am thinking to use OrientDB but hate its SQL extended lang.

Bottomline: It is very awkward to say some data have very different model from that relational databases can model easily and build graph db to model it, and then adopt sql to query it. Aggghhhh!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe partially in some limited circumstances, but generally no.

Translating the actual query isn't even really the issue, it's more translating the data model.  Consider that SQL is querying a relational model with primary/foreign key relationships and tables, and Cypher is doing something completely different.  These two things aren't translatable for each other because you'd have to first know how a relational model mapped onto a graph model in order to even approach this, and such a general mapping for any model doesn't exist.

Gremlin is a different issue, it supports imperative graph traversal, while Cypher is a declarative graph query language.  They're both based on graphs, but their approach is different enough that the answer is still no.